# Adding columns to a file based on existing columns

Tags: perl, awk, calculated-columns, csv

I am trying to modify a file which is set up like this:

```
chr start   ref alt 
chr1    18884   C   CAAAA
chr1    135419  TATACA  T
chr1    332045  T   TTG
chr1    453838  T   TAC
chr1    567652  T   TG
chr1    602541  TTTA    T
chr1    614937  C   CTCTCTG
chr1    654889  C   CA
chr1    736800  AC  A
```

I want to modify it such that:
if column "ref" is a string >1 (i.e line 2) then I generate 2 new columns where:

first new column = start coordinate-1
second new column = start coordinate+(length of string in ref)+1

therefore, for line 2 output would look like:

```
chr1 135419 TATACA T 135418 135426
```

**or:**
if length of string in "ref" = 1 and column "alt"=string of length>1 (i.e. line 1) then

first new column = start coordinate
second new column = start coordinate+2

so, output for line 1 would be:

```
chr1 18884 C CAAAA 18884 18886
```

I have tried to this in awk but without success 
My perl is non-existent but would this be the best way? Or maybe in R?

Comment: If I read correctly the specs, your two if's collapse in one (as 1 + 1 = 2) unless you actually have cases in which alt can be missing. If so (alt can miss) then you prob'ly have a fixed record field input and specs are missing - because every solution below splits on white space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perl solution. Note that your specification does not mention what to do if both strings are length 1.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw(say);

#use Data::Dumper;
<DATA>; # Skip the header;
while (<DATA>) {
    my ($chr, $start, $ref, $alt) = split;
    my @cols;
    if (1 < length $ref) {
          @cols = ( $start - 1, $start + 1 + length $ref);
    } elsif (1 < length $alt) {
        @cols = ($start, $start + 2);
    } else {
        warn "Don't know what to do at $.\n";
    }
    say join "\t", $chr, $start, $ref, $alt, @cols;
}


__DATA__
chr start   ref alt
chr1    18884   C   CAAAA
chr1    135419  TATACA  T
chr1    332045  T   TTG
chr1    453838  T   TAC
chr1    567652  T   TG
chr1    602541  TTTA    T
chr1    614937  C   CTCTCTG
chr1    654889  C   CA
chr1    736800  AC  A
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way using `awk`. Run like:

```
awk -f script.awk file | column -t
```

Contents of `script.awk`:

```
NR==1 {
    next
}

length($3)>1 && length($4)==1 {
    print $0, $2-1, $2+length($3)+1
    next
}

length($3)==1 && length($4)>1 {
    print $0, $2, $2+2
    next
}1
```

Results:

```
chr1  18884   C       CAAAA    18884   18886
chr1  135419  TATACA  T        135418  135426
chr1  332045  T       TTG      332045  332047
chr1  453838  T       TAC      453838  453840
chr1  567652  T       TG       567652  567654
chr1  602541  TTTA    T        602540  602546
chr1  614937  C       CTCTCTG  614937  614939
chr1  654889  C       CA       654889  654891
chr1  736800  AC      A        736799  736803
```

Alternatively, here's the one-liner:

```
awk 'NR==1 { next } length($3)>1 && length($4)==1 { print $0, $2-1, $2+length($3)+1; next } length($3)==1 && length($4)>1 { print $0, $2, $2+2; next }1' filem | column -t
```

---

The code should be pretty self-explanatory. The `1` on the end of the script simply enables default printing (i.e. '1' returns true) of each line. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Doing it in perl is trivial (but so is in awk):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
while (<>) {
  chmop;
  my ($chr,$start,$ref,$alt)=split(/\s+/,$_);
  if (len($ref) > 1) {
print STDOUT
  "$chr\t$start\t$ref\t$alt\t",
    $start+len($ref)+1,"\n";
  } elsif (len($ref)==1) {
print STDOUT
  "$chr\t$start\t$ref\t$alt\t",
    $start+2,"\n";
  } else {
print STDERR "ERROR: ???\n"; #actually impossible
  }
}
```

Stick it in a file morecols.pl , chmod +x morecols.pl, run more morecols.pl . (Beware, lots of assumptions in this code/instructions). I have a feeling your actual problem is more with programming/text processing then tools or languages. If so, this code is just a stopgap solution....

Cheers.